z3 OCaml module linking error in "dune utop"
I have to execute z3 module in OCaml.
But when I try to execute dune utop then I meet under error
mingyu809@DESKTOP-NTK8E0T:~/ocaml/COSE419-2024-main/hw2$ dune utop
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Error on dynamically loaded library: /home/mingyu809/.opam/default/lib/lwt/../stublibs/dllz3ml.so: /home/mingyu809/.opam/default/lib/lwt/../stublibs/dllz3ml.so: undefined symbol: Z3_mk_u32string

But I execute dune build and dune exec -- ./main.exe, it works well.
I use WSL2 on Windows 11
I tried to remove opam and other package and reinstall but same error occurs.
